# Calculate correlation coefficient

Tags: probability

Let $U$ be a random variable with uniform distribution in $(0,1)$. We define $X=\sin(2\pi U)$ and $Y=\cos(2\pi U)$. Calculate the correlation coefficient between $X$ and $Y$, that is:
$$\mbox{Corr}(X,Y)=\frac{\mbox{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y}$$
I am having trouble calculating the covariance since I don't know the common pdf, only the marginal ones, and since $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, I can't figure out how to do this. Could someone help me please?

Comment: Remember that $Cov(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]$. To compute the expected values, use LOTUS.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2754649/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
EXY=E(\sin2 \pi U\cos2 \pi U)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\sin2 \pi u\cos2 \pi uf_{U}(u)\, du=\int_{0}^1
\sin2 \pi u\cos2 \pi u\, du
$$
where $f_{U}$ is the density of a uniform and we have used the [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician).

Comment: Also recall $2 \sin (x)\cos(x)=\sin(2x)$ .